# loading text file and accessing data using tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a text file of size (20480,8). I want the data in 4th column in to one array. I am able to do it using python as

```
file_pathname1 = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'),'TF','1st_test', '20.10.22.12.09.13')
x= np.loadtext(file_pathname1)
y= x[:,4]
#print(np.shape(x))
print(np.shape(y))
```

I get the size of the y as (20480,)

but I am trying to copy the same as a tensor. How to access the data

```
file_pathname1 = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'),'TF','1st_test', '20.10.22.12.09.13')
y = tf.read_file(file_pathname1)
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(y)
print(y.get_shape())
```

I cant understand whether I have loaded the file correctly as I am getting it as empty array
    `()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found the solution posting if it helps someone

```
x1 = tf.constant(y,name = 'x1')
model = tf.initialize_all_variables()
with tf.Session() as session:
     session.run(model)
print(np.shape(session.run(x1)))
```